# What is the probability that the randomly selected onto function maps prime numbers to prime numbers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, functions

Let $X=\{1,2,3,...,25\}$. If a student selects a function randomly from the set of all functions from $X$ onto $X$,then what is the probability that the selected function maps prime numbers to prime numbers?

please reply in factorial format no need to open the factorials

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes thank you